# Verification to use Schwarz' Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

In Robinson's Functions of One Complex Variable I, the author states that if a $f$ is a non-constant analytic function with $f(z)\leq 1$ for all $|z|\leq 1$, then the function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-a}{1-\overline{a}f(z)}$ maps $D$ into $D$, where $f(a)=0$. Why is it the case that $|g(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z$ in $D$? I've tried using the triangle inequality on the numerator, as well as multiplying the numerator and denominator by both $a$ and $\overline{a}$, but I can't seem to get the inequality to work out. How can I see this?

Comment: Consider $|1-\overline ab|^2-|b-a|^2$ for $b=f(z)$.

Comment: Or, perhaps more straightforward, compute the absolute value $\left|\dfrac{b-a}{1-\bar ab}\right|$ when $a$ and $b$ satisfy $|a|,|b|\le 1$ (and, of course, $\bar ab \ne 1$).

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, that is the goal. But is there some trick that I'm missing beyond the ones I mentioned above?

Comment: You seem to have missed the most obvious thing to try. Multiply the given fraction by its conjugate and see what happens!

Comment: @TedShifrin $(|a|^2+|b|^2-2Re(\overline{a}b))/(|ab|^2+1-2Re(\overline{a}b))$. What 
"obvious" thing am I missing here?

Comment: So now you have a fraction of positive real numbers. $q/r\le 1$ is equivalent to $q\le r$, right? [Soon you will be at the "hint" that Lord Shark gave you!]

Comment: @TedShifrin The only thing I gather from Lord Shark's comment is that the result follows if $|1-\overline{a}b|^2-|b-a|^2\geq 0$. The expression I've written above of the fraction times its conjugate is greater than or equal to $0$, and we'd like to show that it's less than or equal to $1$. I'm not sure if the quantity says something about  $|1-\overline{a}b|^2-|b-a|^2\geq 0$.

Comment: So doesn't $q/r\le 1$ turn into $|a|^2+|b|^2\le 1+|a|^2|b|^2$? When does that inequality hold?

Comment: @TedShifrin It holds when $1+|a|^2|b|^2-|a|^2-|b|^2=|1-\overline{a}b|^2-|b-a|^2\geq 0$?

Comment: Ignore that. Just do basic high school algebra with what we have. When is $x\le y$? Answer: When $y-x\ge 0$. Now show that that holds in your case.

Comment: Got it. Factoring gets us $(|a|^2-1)(|b|^2-1)\geq 0$, which is true when $|a|,|b|\leq 1$

Comment: There you go! Proceed!